How do you specify "80 Ms" or "120 Ms" with commands like keywait?
The keywait command expects its T parameter to be in seconds:
T: Timeout (e.g. T3). The number of seconds to wait before timing out and setting ErrorLevel to 1

It's not flexible like sleep, where I can specify sleep units in MS. So how does one specify very specific units like like 80 Ms or 120 Ms?
For example, I wrote the following give me a 80 Ms or 120 waiting time in MS, I am not sure if it is correct though.
KeyWait, RShift, t00.0080   ;is this 80ms???
KeyWait, RShift, t00.0120   ;is this 80ms???

Do the two lines of code indeed correctly correspond to 80/120 mS?

ms ("milliseconds") are thousandths of a second, so 120ms <-> 0.12s. Ms ("megaseconds") would be millions of seconds, so 120Ms <--> 120,000,000s.
